# C++ Access Autoconf Variable Datadir

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake

I am creating a program called spellcheck, and I'm using autoconf and automake to create a build system for it. The program relies on the dictionary 'english.dict', which is in the data directory (based on whatever prefix the user selected). I want the data directory path accessible by spellcheck, so I created a custom variable that contained its value:

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT(libspellcheck, 1.25, corinthianmonthly@hotmail.com)
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile libspellcheck/Makefile spellcheck/Makefile man/Makefile)
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([])

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([DATA_PATH], ["$pkgdatadir"],"DData Directory Path")
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_RANLIB



# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h,iostream,fstream,string,stdio.h,sstream,cctype,algorithm,boost/algorithm/string.hpp])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_CHECK_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.

AC_OUTPUT
```

However, in the config.h file, this value is blank:

```
/* config.h.  Generated from config.h.in by configure.  */
/* config.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader.  */

/* "Description" */
#define DATA_PATH ""

...
```

I tried changing $pkgdatadir to $datadir, but I got the same result. What am I doing wrong, or is what I am trying to achieve impossible?

EDIT: I redefined the variable in my Makefile.am for spellcheck:

```
AM_CFLAGS = -DDATA_PATH=\"$(pkgdatadir)\" -m32 -Wall 




bin_PROGRAMS = spellcheck
pkgdata_DATA = english.dict
spellcheck_SOURCES = spellcheck.cpp meta.cpp 
spellcheck_LDADD = ../libspellcheck/libspellcheck.a
```

But now it complains about DATA_PATH being nonexistant:

```
spellcheck.cpp:4:22: error: 'DATA_PATH' was not declared in this scope
 #define DEFAULT_DICT DATA_PATH "english.dict"
```

Because now it seems to be ignoring all CFLAGS:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT spellcheck.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/spellcheck.Tpo -c -o spellcheck.o spellcheck.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to use AM_CPPFLAGS rather than CFLAGS.